# Java needing enter pressed twice

Tags: java

I know that this question has been answered countless times, and I have read an unreasonable amount of articles on this! However, I can just not figure it out and would love any input for this. I am making a tic tac toe game and in my main function, I am calling for the user to input which square to play in. Rather than just entering "3" and hitting enter, you have to press enter twice. Heres the code:

```
    int N = 0;
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("PLease choose a spot to place in (0 to quit): ");

            if(input.hasNextInt())
                {
                 N = input.nextInt();
                }
            else
                {

                input.nextLine();
                System.out.println("That wasn't a number, please enter a number( 0 to quit)");
                //continue;
                }

            if(N < 0 || N > 9)
                {
                System.out.println("That's not a valid choice, please pick another!");
                //continue;
                }
            if (N != 0)
                {
                Person.BoardUpdater(N,Game.GameBoard, "O");     
                Comp.AI(Game.GameBoard, "O" , "X");
                Game.draw(Game.GameBoard);

                }
            else
                {
                break;
                }


        }
```

Comment: So what happens when you don't hit enter twice? Or are you looking for a solution which would require user to hit enter twice and aren't getting it?

Comment: If I hit it twice it moves on with the program, I'm looking to be able to only hit enter once

Comment: According to most Java coding conventions, variables and methods begin with a lower case letter. Classes typically use an upper case letter.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure about this, but just try it and see if it works.

```
if(input.hasNextInt())
 {
  N = input.nextInt();
 }
else
    {
     // ...
```

You use `hasNextInt()` and then `nextLine()`. The scanner is seeing `nextInt()`, and judging if the next line has an int. Then, `nextLine()` goes to the ***next*** line after that, and reads that line. You can fix this with a single call of `nextLine()`, then use `Integer.parseInt()` to convert to a number. If you want to check if it is valid here is a good place to look: [How to check if a String is numeric in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102891/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-numeric-in-java). But if you want to see the basic answer, you have this method:

```
try {
    Integer.parseInt(s); // where s is a String
    return true;
} catch(NumberFormatException e) {
    return false;
}
```

Of course this is a slow way, but it's the easiest.